# Using C#, how do I set a Rally weblink field?

Tags: c#, .net, rally

Here's a screenshot of the field I'm trying to update:

[image]

How do I update the URL field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebLink type fields consist of two parts: LinkID and DisplayString. In order to set a LinkID (which corresponds to the variable ${id} in your screenshot, a DisplayString needs also to be set to an empty string.

Here is a full code example that uses Rally .NET REST toolkit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace aRestApp_CollectionOfTasks
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;
            restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "secret", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");

            //Set our Workspace and Project scopings
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1111"; //please replace this OID with an OID of your workspace 
            String projectRef = "/project/2222";     //please replace this OID with an OID of your project
            bool projectScopingUp = false;
            bool projectScopingDown = true;

            Request storyRequest = new Request("Defect");


            storyRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            storyRequest.Project = projectRef;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeUp = projectScopingUp;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeDown = projectScopingDown;

            storyRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "_ref",
                    "c_JiraLink"
                };

            storyRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, "DE170");       
            QueryResult queryStoryResults = restApi.Query(storyRequest);

            foreach (var s in queryStoryResults.Results)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(" Name: " + s["Name"] + " JiraLink's DisplayString: " + s["c_JiraLink"]["DisplayString"] + " JiraLink's LinkID: " + s["c_JiraLink"]["LinkID"]);  
               DynamicJsonObject toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();
               DynamicJsonObject myLink = new DynamicJsonObject();
               myLink["LinkID"] = "NM-3";
               myLink["DisplayString"] = "";
               toUpdate["c_JiraLink"] = myLink;

               OperationResult updateResult = restApi.Update(s["_ref"], toUpdate);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is not different from a more general example of setting LinkID of a WebLink type of filed using a browser's REST client.

Method: POST

URL:

`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/3807704995?key=abc123...`

Request Body:

```
{
"defect":
{
"c_JiraLink":{
"DisplayString":"",
"LinkID":"NM-2"
}
}
}
```