# Update userdefine field in UserStory via Rally REST API

Tags: java, rest, rally

I created user-define field in UserStory with type "weblink". I see this field in "Custom" section. 
I wrote next code for update this field.

```
        QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");

        storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("TestRailsRef"));
        storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "US1"));

        QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);

        JsonObject storyJsonObject = storyQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();

        String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();

        JsonObject updatedDefect = new JsonObject();
        updatedDefect.addProperty("LinkID", "280");
        updatedDefect.addProperty("DisplayString", "Link to TestRails");
        JsonObject updatedTestRailRef = new JsonObject();
        updatedTestRailRef.add("c_TestRailsRef", updatedDefect);
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(storyRef, updatedDefect);
        UpdateResponse updateResponse = restApi.update(updateRequest);
```

I see warning in updateResponse

```
"{"OperationResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": [], "Warnings": ["It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources.", "Ignored JSON element hierarchicalrequirement.LinkID during processing of this request.", "Ignored JSON element hierarchicalrequirement.DisplayString during processing of this request."]
```

WHY?

Answer (score 0):

WebLink type fields consist of two parts: LinkID and DisplayString. In order to set a LinkID a DisplayString needs to be set to an empty string.

Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450011/using-c-how-do-i-set-a-rally-weblink-field/18450105#18450105) will help.